# отправка эмодзи из списка

Tags: python, json, telegram, unicode

С недавних пор начал интересоваться питоном и решил написать семейного бота. Все конфиги и словари затолкал в conf.json и по мере необходимости подтягиваю от туда то что мне надо. Появилась необходимость декорации текста бота рандомными смайликами и тут началось. Если я задаю список смайлов для рандомной выборки в теле программы, то никаких проблем не возникает, смайлы отправляются в необходимом виде, а если он подтягивает значение из conf.json то в чате я вижу unicode обозначение эмодзи.

часть конфига:

```
"smile": [
    "\\U0001F4A8",
    "\\U0001F4A9",
    "\\U0001F4A5",
    "\\U0001F4A2",
    "\\U0001F4A6"
]
```

часть кода:

```
def get_smile():
with open(conf, 'r') as read:
    x = read.read()
    x = json.loads(x)
return(x['smile'])
smile = get_smile()
smile_len = len(smile)-1
smile_random = random.randint(0,smile_len)
smile_random = str(smile[smile_random])
if first_word == 'уроки' or first_word == 'расписание':
    if len(text) == 1:
        t = len(timetable)-1
        z = get_time()
        messaga = smile_random+' Уроки у Каринки заканчиваются в '+z[(t)]+' '+smile_random
        print(messaga)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, messaga)
```

Мне кажется, что в какой то момент возникают проблемы с кодировкой, но я пока только учусь)
буду признателен за советы.

Comment: Как добавляли данные в файл? Как они выглядят в файле?

Comment: добавлял вручную. выглядят в файле как в фрагменте с частью конфига. пробовал разные варианты. изначально были проблемы с использованием знака '\' в json. пришлось использовать "обертку" и добавлять еще один слэш. Мне кажется, что именно в этом моменте у меня возникают проблемы. Плюс у меня этот файл конфигурации постоянно переписывается при внесении поправок. и в этот момент могут возникать проблемы.

Comment: *>>Если я задаю список смайлов ... в теле программы* - как задавали в теле программы?